# How does "to subsist in" come to mean "to be attributed to"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, verbs

What's the logical derivation behind this definition of *[subsist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/subsist?q=subsist)* [Definition 2.1]

> Be attributable to:
>   *the effect of genetic maldevelopment may subsist in chromosomal mutation*

In that link, the etymology is listed as:

> mid 16th century (in the sense 'continue to exist'): from Latin subsistere 'stand firm',
>    from sub- 'from below' + sistere 'set, stand'.

How does this etymology lead to the meaning "to be attributed to" ?

Comment: The *be attributable to* sense represents a further shift from original *[have life] maintained by sustenance --> [reflexive] maintain or support oneself --> to remain in existence --> to consist, lie, or reside **in** some specified thing, circumstance, fact, etc.* By the end of that chain, "genetic maldevelopment" ***exists*** through "chromosomal mutation", which comes to much the same thing as saying that's the ***cause*** of it.

Comment: *attributable to* is not the same as *attributed to*, any more than *believable* is the same as *believed*.